# org-mode - where's the complete list of exporter options for publishing?

Tags: emacs, publish, org-mode

I'm checking the list from the [official documentation of the latest version](http://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-options.html), but it doesn't seem comprehensive. According to my Web searches, there are other properties like `:auto-sitemap`, `:auto-preamble`, etc. that are absent in this list. Where can I get the full list?

Comment: Org's documentation is *exceptional*. I doubt that it has many errors. However, it documents the current version of Org (8.2.6 at the time of this writing), which can be very different from what you're running (I believe that Emacs currently ships with Org version 7.9.3f or so). Where have you seen `:auto-sitemap` and `:auto-preamble`? They may have existed in previous versions. It is also possible that you are using a *pre*-release version of Org, and the documentation has not yet caught up. In that case, `C-h i m org RET publishing opt RET` should show you what you've really got.

Comment: Before I read your comment, I had actually just installed the new version from m/elpa. Now I'm having problems with `org-with-silent-modifications`.

Comment: This doesn't help. What does "having problems with `org-with-silent-modifications`" mean? Are these *different* problems from the ones in your question?

Comment: I've just fixed it by re-installing org on fresh session. However, my generated HTML pages says that my org version is still 7.9.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a *full list*. You already mentioned the Manual's Section [Options for the Exporters](https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-options.html). Perhaps you might be happy with the Worg blog [Org Export Reference Documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-export-reference.html).

The publishing specifications are arranged into subsections of the Manual's Publishing  [Configuration](https://orgmode.org/manual/Configuration.html) Section. And the export specifications are scattered through the corresponding export sections. For example ...

`:auto-preamble` is from an older ORG version, and as Guerry's [git commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/da8dc7bba72613131.f97a28f1c4a912b8d85d7cc) states, was substituted by `:html-preamble`, linked to `org-export-html-preamble` then. Currently it's linked to `org-html-preamble` and described in the Manual's Section [HTML preamble and postamble](https://orgmode.org/manual/HTML-preamble-and-postamble.html).

`:auto-sitemap` is still available and described in Section [Generating a Sitemap](https://orgmode.org/manual/Sitemap.html)

(Ubuntu 18.04, Emacs 25.2.2, Org-Mode 9.2.1)

(The git commit link above was from a Google cache, and throws a 404. It was one of the first results of the search for `org-mode ":auto-preamble"`. The commit was around 2011.)